# Can not build DJI sample application due to missing required architecture armv7

Tags: dji-sdk

I am trying to update the DJI SDK of my app to the latest version (i.e. `v4.10` for DJISDK/UXSDK and `v1.5` for DJIWidget) in order for it to be compatible with Matrice 200 V2 series. I have come across an error which I was able to reproduce as well with the sample application from the [DJI Mobile-UXSDK-iOS repo](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS).

Basically when I try to archive the app it have this error showing up:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/nachocarnicero/git/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS/Sample Code/ObjcSampleCode/Frameworks'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/nachocarnicero/git/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS/Sample Code/ObjcSampleCode/../DJIWidget'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/nachocarnicero/git/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS/Sample Code/ObjcSampleCode/Pods/DJI-UXSDK-iOS/iOS_UXSDK/DJIUXSDK.framework/DJIUXSDK, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/nachocarnicero/git/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS/Sample Code/ObjcSampleCode/Pods/DJI-UXSDK-iOS/iOS_UXSDK/DJIUXSDK.framework/DJIUXSDK (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/nachocarnicero/git/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS/Sample Code/ObjcSampleCode/Pods/DJI-SDK-iOS/iOS_Mobile_SDK/DJISDK.framework/DJISDK, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/nachocarnicero/git/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS/Sample Code/ObjcSampleCode/Pods/DJI-SDK-iOS/iOS_Mobile_SDK/DJISDK.framework/DJISDK (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DUXBatteryWidget", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MyBatteryWidget in MyBatteryWidget.o
      objc-class-ref in PanelsCollectionsViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_DUXDefaultLayoutViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DefaultLayoutViewController in DefaultLayoutViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_DUXBatteryWidget", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MyBatteryWidget in MyBatteryWidget.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DUXStatusBarViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PanelsCollectionsViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DUXDefaultLayoutViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_DefaultLayoutViewController in DefaultLayoutViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DJISDKManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MainViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Before this version everything worked fine, so I guess it is a problem with the newest DJI SDK version.

I am using the ObjectiveC sample code, and the app works fine in debug mode running it on an iPad Pro.

Comment: should send report to dev@dji.com. Every time DJI update something, they trys to create funny bugs.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is running into this problem, it seems that the new DJI SDK is not compatible with armv7 architectures, so the solution here is to go to the XCode Build Settings tab of your project and remove `armv7` under `Valid Architectures` as it was done by [this commit](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-iOS/commit/41f36c934c8b8308a8ef44501a46edaf7f9aa211) on the DJI Mobile-SDK-iOS repo.